# Hadoop: Run MapReduce jobs on specific group of servers

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

Currently, we are using Hadoop in 3 separate projects on production, each cluster consists of different type of servers:

1. Cluster 1: 35TB storage, medium memory and medium CPU
2. Cluster 2: 200TB storage, high memory and medium CPU
3. Cluster 3: 60TB storage, high memory, high CPU and SSD harddisks

Now we want to make 1 cluster out of the 3 groups. So all data would be distributed among members of each group. Yet we want to schedule tasks that are specific to certain servers. For instance I want to fire up a task that should only work on cluster 1 members.

Is that possible? If yes how?

Comment: Might be better asked on serverfault.com